# Laravel blade render crashes the img src using asset()

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, laravel-blade

I stored my HTML in database in which i have some images and the src is given by laravel asset helper but while rendering it on view using laravel html renderer {!! !!}
the {{asset("img/abc.jpg")}} in src attribute of img tag is not working it's shown in the same way in src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing something wrong. if asset("img/abc.jpg") is stored in database, you actually have saved the blade engine template, not the rendered HTML.
In the rendered HTML, you should have something like this:

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/abc.jpg">
```

instead of asset("img/abc.jpg"), which doesn't need any further coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since the template is not in a view Laravel won't know that it contains Blade syntax, so you'll have to render it manually:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
 
return Blade::render('Hello, {{ $name }}', ['name' => 'Julian Bashir']);
```

Source: [Laravel Docs - Rendering Inline Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates)